# What's the term for the emphasis on the first words in a body of text?

Tags: typography, terminology

Is there a formal term for when the first word(s) or line of an article are emphasized?

For example, on Wired, the first three words are set in small caps for emphasis, and I've seen similar things in print too. Is there a name for this?

> [image: First three words emphasized on Wired]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure how universal the term is, but I have always known them as a "Lead-in". Usually set in small-caps, but often emphasised in other ways (bold, italics, color variations etc).

You can see some more examples here: http://creativepro.com/designing-lead-ins/